# Console is crashing, unable to identify error yet?

Tags: c++

It actually displays the correct msg in the console but then crashes almost immediately after.

```
#ifndef NODE_H
#define NODE_H

template <typename T>
class Node
{
private:
    T m_Data;
    Node<T>* m_Next;
    Node<T>* m_Prev;
public:
    Node();
    Node(const T& m_Data);
    Node(const Node<T>& rhs);
    ~Node();

    Node<T>* getNext() const;
    Node<T>* getPrev() const;
    Node<T>& operator=(const Node<T>& rhs);
    T getData();
    void destroy();

    void setNext(Node<T>* n);
    void setPrev( Node<T>* p);
    void setData(const T& data);
};

template <typename T>
Node<T>::Node()
{
    m_Data = T();
    m_Next = nullptr;
    m_Prev = nullptr;
}

template <typename T>
Node<T>::Node(const Node<T>& rhs) {
    *this = rhs;
}

template <typename T>
Node<T>& Node<T>::operator=(const Node<T>& n) {
    if (this == &n) {
        return *this;
    }
    delete this;
    Node<T> tmp = new Node<T>(n.m_Data);
    tmp.setNext(n.getNext());
    tmp.setPrev(n.getPrev());

    *this = tmp;

    return *this;
}

template <typename T>
Node<T>::Node(const T& data)
{
    m_Data = data;
    m_Next = nullptr;
    m_Prev = nullptr;
}

template <typename T>
Node<T>::~Node()
{
    setNext(nullptr);
    setPrev(nullptr);
}

template <typename T>
void Node<T>::destroy()
{
    m_Data = T();
    setNext(nullptr);
    setPrev(nullptr);
}

#endif 


#ifndef LINKEDLIST_H
#define LINKEDLIST_H
#include "Node.h"
#include <iostream>

using namespace std; 

template <typename T>
class LinkedL
{
public:
    LinkedL();
    ~LinkedL();
    LinkedL(const LinkedL<T>& rhs);
    LinkedL<T>& operator=(const LinkedL<T>& rhs);

    void insertFirst(const T& data);
    void insertLast(const T& data);
    void insertAfter(const T& key, const T& data);
    void destroy();

    bool isEmpty();
    int getSize()const;
    bool remove(int i);
    void traverseForward();

    T operator[](int i);

private:
    Node<T>* getNode(int i) const;
    Node<T>* m_First;
    Node<T>* m_Last;
    int m_Size;
};

template <typename T>
LinkedL<T>::LinkedL()
{
    m_First = nullptr;
    m_Last = nullptr;
    m_Size = 0;
}

template <typename T>
LinkedL<T>::LinkedL(const LinkedL<T>& rhs) {
    *this = rhs;
}

template <typename T>
LinkedL<T>& LinkedL<T>::operator=(const LinkedL<T>& rhs) {
    if (this == &rhs) {
        return *this;
    } 

    destroy();

    m_Size = rhs.m_Size;
    Node<T>* head = new Node<T>(rhs.m_First->getData());
    insertFirst(head->getData());

    Node<T>* current = rhs.m_First->getNext();
    while (current != nullptr) {
        insertLast(current->getData());
        current = current->getNext();
    }

    return *this;
}

template <typename T>
void LinkedL<T>::destroy() {
    if (m_First != nullptr) {
        Node<T>* current = m_First;
        while (current != nullptr) {
            Node<T>* oldNode = current;
            current = current->getNext();
            delete oldNode;
            oldNode = 0;
        }
    }
}

template <typename T>
void LinkedL<T>::insertFirst(const T& data) {
    Node<T>* newNode = new Node<T>(data);
    if (isEmpty()) {
        m_First = newNode;
        m_Last = newNode;
    }
    else {
        m_First->setPrev(newNode);
        newNode->setNext(m_First);
        m_First = newNode;
    }
    m_Size++;
}

template <typename T>
void LinkedL<T>::insertLast(const T& data) {
    Node<T>* newNode = new Node<T>(data);
    if (isEmpty()) {
        m_Last = newNode;
        m_First = newNode;
    }
    else {
        m_Last->setNext(newNode);
        newNode->setPrev(m_Last);
        m_Last = newNode;
    }
    m_Size++;
}

template <typename T>
T LinkedL<T>::operator[](int i) {
    int counter = 0;
    Node<T>* current = m_First;

    while (true) {
        if (counter == i) {
            return (current->getData());
        }
        current = current->getNext();
        counter++;
    }
}

template <typename T>
Node<T>* LinkedL<T>::getNode(int i) const{
    int counter = 0;
    Node<T>* current = m_First;
    if (i<0 && i>=this->getSize()) {
        return nullptr;
    }
    while (true) {
        if (counter == i) {
            return current;
        }
        current = current->getNext();
        counter++;
    }
}

template <typename T>
bool LinkedL<T>::remove(int i) {

    if (isEmpty() || i<0 || i>=getSize()) {
        cout << "No nodes to remove in specified index" << endl;
        return false;
    }
    Node<T>* iNode = getNode(i);

    if (getSize()==1) { //only 1 element in the list
        m_Last = iNode->getNext();
        m_First = nullptr;
        delete iNode;
    }
    else if (i==0) { //remove first element
        Node<T>* next = getNode(i + 1);
        next->setPrev(nullptr);
        m_First = next;
        delete iNode;
    }
    else if(i==(getSize()-1)){//remove last element
        Node<T>* prev = getNode(i - 1);
        prev->setNext(nullptr);
        m_Last = prev;
        delete iNode;
    }
    else { //remove "sandwiched" element
        Node<T>* prev = getNode(i - 1);
        Node<T>* next = getNode(i + 1);
        prev->setNext(next);
        next->setPrev(prev);
        delete iNode;
    }
    m_Size--;
    return true;
}

template <typename T>
void LinkedL<T>::traverseForward() {
    for (int i = 0; i < getSize(); i++) {
        cout << "[" << i << "] " << this->operator[](i) << "  ";
    }
}

#endif // !LINKEDLIST_H


#include <iostream>
#include "LinkedL.h"
#include "Node.h"
using std::cout;
using std::endl;



int main() {

    LinkedL<int> list;
    list.insertFirst(31);
    list.insertLast(23);
    list.insertAfter(23, 67);
    list.insertAfter(23, 45);
    LinkedL<int> list1(list);
    list.destroy();
    list1.traverseForward();

    system("PAUSE");
}
```

Any comments on my style would also be greatly appreciated. It's kind of driving me nuts and I'm almost there...

Comment: That's a lot code to go through to find any bugs that you might have. Please post a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: You don't need to use `getNode` in `remove` since you already know the previous and next nodes. In the worst case, you're traversing the list ~3 times just to remove one node.

Answer (score 1):

First mistake. You forgot to initialize member variable in copy constructor:

```
template <typename T>
LinkedL<T>::LinkedL(const LinkedL<T>& rhs):m_First(nullptr),m_Last(nullptr),m_Size(0)
{
    *this = rhs;
}
```

Second mistake, you are initializing and again incrementing m_Size variable. Commented below:

```
template <typename T>
LinkedL<T>& LinkedL<T>::operator=(const LinkedL<T>& rhs) {
    if (this == &rhs) {
        return *this;
    } 

    destroy();

    //m_Size = rhs.m_Size;
    Node<T>* head = new Node<T>(rhs.m_First->getData());
    insertFirst(head->getData());

    Node<T>* current = rhs.m_First->getNext();
    while (current != nullptr) {
        insertLast(current->getData());
        current = current->getNext();
    }

    return *this;
}
```

Complete code. Enjoy:

```
 #ifndef NODE_H
#define NODE_H

template <typename T>
class Node
{
private:
    T m_Data;
    Node<T>* m_Next;
    Node<T>* m_Prev;
public:
    Node();
    Node(const T& m_Data);
    Node(const Node<T>& rhs);
    ~Node();

    Node<T>* getNext() const;
    Node<T>* getPrev() const;
    Node<T>& operator=(const Node<T>& rhs);
    T getData();
    void destroy();

    void setNext(Node<T>* n);
    void setPrev( Node<T>* p);
    void setData(const T& data);
};

template <typename T>
Node<T>::Node()
{
    m_Data = T();
    m_Next = nullptr;
    m_Prev = nullptr;
}

template <typename T>
Node<T>::Node(const Node<T>& rhs) {
    *this = rhs;
}

template <typename T>
Node<T>& Node<T>::operator=(const Node<T>& n) {
    if (this == &n) {
        return *this;
    }
    delete this;
    Node<T> tmp = new Node<T>(n.m_Data);
    tmp.setNext(n.getNext());
    tmp.setPrev(n.getPrev());

    *this = tmp;

    return *this;
}

template <typename T>
Node<T>::Node(const T& data)
{
    m_Data = data;
    m_Next = nullptr;
    m_Prev = nullptr;
}

template <typename T>
Node<T>::~Node()
{
    setNext(nullptr);
    setPrev(nullptr);
}

template <typename T>
void Node<T>::destroy()
{
    m_Data = T();
    setNext(nullptr);
    setPrev(nullptr);
}

template <typename T>
Node<T>* Node<T>::getNext() const {
    return m_Next;
}

template <typename T>
Node<T>* Node<T>::getPrev() const {
    return m_Prev;
}

template <typename T>
void Node<T>::setNext(Node<T>* n) {
    m_Next = n;
}

template <typename T>
void Node<T>::setPrev(Node<T>* p) {
    m_Prev = p;
}

template <typename T>
void Node<T>::setData(const T& data) {
    m_Data = data;
}

template <typename T>
T Node<T>::getData() {
    return m_Data;
}

#endif 


#ifndef LINKEDLIST_H
#define LINKEDLIST_H
//#include "Node.h"
#include <iostream>

using namespace std; 

template <typename T>
class LinkedL
{
public:
    LinkedL();
    ~LinkedL();
    LinkedL(const LinkedL<T>& rhs);
    LinkedL<T>& operator=(const LinkedL<T>& rhs);

    void insertFirst(const T& data);
    void insertLast(const T& data);
    void insertAfter(const T& key, const T& data);
    void destroy();

    bool isEmpty();
    int getSize()const;
    bool remove(int i);
    void traverseForward();

    T operator[](int i);

private:
    Node<T>* getNode(int i) const;
    Node<T>* m_First;
    Node<T>* m_Last;
    int m_Size;
};

template <typename T>
LinkedL<T>::LinkedL()
{
    m_First = nullptr;
    m_Last = nullptr;
    m_Size = 0;
}

template <typename T>
LinkedL<T>::~LinkedL()
{
    destroy();
}

template <typename T>
LinkedL<T>::LinkedL(const LinkedL<T>& rhs):m_First(nullptr),m_Last(nullptr),m_Size(0)
{
    *this = rhs;
}

template <typename T>
LinkedL<T>& LinkedL<T>::operator=(const LinkedL<T>& rhs) {
    if (this == &rhs) {
        return *this;
    } 

    destroy();

    //m_Size = rhs.m_Size;
    Node<T>* head = new Node<T>(rhs.m_First->getData());
    insertFirst(head->getData());

    Node<T>* current = rhs.m_First->getNext();
    while (current != nullptr) {
        insertLast(current->getData());
        current = current->getNext();
    }

    return *this;
}

template <typename T>
void LinkedL<T>::destroy() {
    if (m_First != nullptr) {
        Node<T>* current = m_First;
        while (current != nullptr) {
            Node<T>* oldNode = current;
            current = current->getNext();
            delete oldNode;
            oldNode = 0;
        }
    }
}

template <typename T>
bool LinkedL<T>::isEmpty() {
    if (m_First == nullptr) {
        return true;
    } return false; 
}

template <typename T>
void LinkedL<T>::insertFirst(const T& data) {
    Node<T>* newNode = new Node<T>(data);
    if (isEmpty()) {
        m_First = newNode;
        m_Last = newNode;
    }
    else {
        m_First->setPrev(newNode);
        newNode->setNext(m_First);
        m_First = newNode;
    }
    m_Size++;
}

template <typename T>
void LinkedL<T>::insertAfter(const T& key, const T& data) {
    if (isEmpty()) {
        return;
    } 
    Node<T>* current=0;
    for (int i = 0; i < this->getSize(); i++) {
        if (this->operator[](i) == key) {
            current = this->getNode(i);
        }
    }
    Node<T>* newNode = new Node<T>(data);
    if (current == 0) {
        cout << "Node could not be found." << endl;
        return;
    }
    else if (current==m_Last) {
        m_Last = newNode;
        newNode->setNext(nullptr);
    }
    else {
        current->getNext()->setPrev(newNode);
        newNode->setNext(current->getNext());
    }
    current->setNext(newNode);
    newNode->setPrev(current);
    m_Size++;
}

template <typename T>
int LinkedL<T>::getSize() const{
    return m_Size;
}

template <typename T>
void LinkedL<T>::insertLast(const T& data) {
    Node<T>* newNode = new Node<T>(data);
    if (isEmpty()) {
        m_Last = newNode;
        m_First = newNode;
    }
    else {
        m_Last->setNext(newNode);
        newNode->setPrev(m_Last);
        m_Last = newNode;
    }
    m_Size++;
}

template <typename T>
T LinkedL<T>::operator[](int i) {
    int counter = 0;
    Node<T>* current = m_First;

    while (true) {
        if (counter == i) {
            return (current->getData());
        }
        current = current->getNext();
        counter++;
    }
}

template <typename T>
Node<T>* LinkedL<T>::getNode(int i) const{
    int counter = 0;
    Node<T>* current = m_First;
    if (i<0 && i>=this->getSize()) {
        return nullptr;
    }
    while (true) {
        if (counter == i) {
            return current;
        }
        current = current->getNext();
        counter++;
    }
}

template <typename T>
bool LinkedL<T>::remove(int i) {

    if (isEmpty() || i<0 || i>=getSize()) {
        cout << "No nodes to remove in specified index" << endl;
        return false;
    }
    Node<T>* iNode = getNode(i);

    if (getSize()==1) { //only 1 element in the list
        m_Last = iNode->getNext();
        m_First = nullptr;
        delete iNode;
    }
    else if (i==0) { //remove first element
        Node<T>* next = getNode(i + 1);
        next->setPrev(nullptr);
        m_First = next;
        delete iNode;
    }
    else if(i==(getSize()-1)){//remove last element
        Node<T>* prev = getNode(i - 1);
        prev->setNext(nullptr);
        m_Last = prev;
        delete iNode;
    }
    else { //remove "sandwiched" element
        Node<T>* prev = getNode(i - 1);
        Node<T>* next = getNode(i + 1);
        prev->setNext(next);
        next->setPrev(prev);
        delete iNode;
    }
    m_Size--;
    return true;
}

template <typename T>
void LinkedL<T>::traverseForward() {
    for (int i = 0; i < getSize(); i++) {
        cout << "[" << i << "] " << this->operator[](i) << "  ";
    }
}

#endif // !LINKEDLIST_H


#include <iostream>
//#include "LinkedL.h"
//#include "Node.h"
using std::cout;
using std::endl;



int main() {

    LinkedL<int> list;
    list.insertFirst(31);
    list.insertLast(23);
    list.insertAfter(23, 67);
    list.insertAfter(23, 45);
    LinkedL<int> list1(list);
    list.destroy();
    list1.traverseForward();

    system("PAUSE");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In order to make the Sumeet solution to work I recommend to add `m_First = nullptr;` at the `destroy` end method, this work ok but be carefully with this code...
build with this command and see the error about memory leak:

```
g++ /tmp/untitled/main.cc -std=c++11 -Wall -Werror -fsanitize=leak -fsanitize=undefined -fno-omit-frame-pointer -fsanitize=leak -fsanitize=undefined -g -o program
```

then run `./program` and see:
[0] 31  [1](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/initializer_list) 23  [2](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Resource_Acquisition_Is_Initialization) 45  [3] 67

==20028==ERROR: LeakSanitizer: detected memory leaks

Direct leak of 24 byte(s) in 1 object(s) allocated from:

```
#0 0x7f765f002aef in operator new(unsigned long) (/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/liblsan.so.0+0xdaef)
#1 0x402377 in LinkedL<int>::operator=(LinkedL<int> const&) /tmp/untitled/main.cc:176
#2 0x401a75 in LinkedL<int>::LinkedL(LinkedL<int> const&) /tmp/untitled/main.cc:164
#3 0x400e13 in main /tmp/untitled/main.cc:365
#4 0x7f765d6c75ef in __libc_start_main (/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6+0x205ef)
```

SUMMARY: LeakSanitizer: 24 byte(s) leaked in 1 allocation(s).

As Sumeet say you forgot to initialize member variable in copy constructor, but I prefer the [delegate contructor solution](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/initializer_list)

Complete code:

```
#ifndef NODE_H
#define NODE_H

template <typename T>
class Node
{
private:
    T m_Data;
    Node<T>* m_Next;
    Node<T>* m_Prev;
public:
    Node();
    Node(const T& m_Data);
    Node(const Node<T>& rhs);
    ~Node();

    Node<T>* getNext() const;
    Node<T>* getPrev() const;
    Node<T>& operator=(const Node<T>& rhs);
    T getData();
    void destroy();

    void setNext(Node<T>* n);
    void setPrev( Node<T>* p);
    void setData(const T& data);
};

template <typename T>
Node<T>::Node()
{
    m_Data = T();
    m_Next = nullptr;
    m_Prev = nullptr;
}

template <typename T>
Node<T>::Node(const Node<T>& rhs) {
    *this = rhs;
}

template <typename T>
Node<T>& Node<T>::operator=(const Node<T>& n) {
    if (this == &n) {
        return *this;
    }
    delete this;
    Node<T> tmp = new Node<T>(n.m_Data);
    tmp.setNext(n.getNext());
    tmp.setPrev(n.getPrev());

    *this = tmp;

    return *this;
}

template <typename T>
Node<T>::Node(const T& data)
{
    m_Data = data;
    m_Next = nullptr;
    m_Prev = nullptr;
}

template <typename T>
Node<T>::~Node()
{
    setNext(nullptr);
    setPrev(nullptr);
}

template <typename T>
void Node<T>::destroy()
{
    m_Data = T();
    setNext(nullptr);
    setPrev(nullptr);
}

template <typename T>
Node<T>* Node<T>::getNext() const {
    return m_Next;
}

template <typename T>
Node<T>* Node<T>::getPrev() const {
    return m_Prev;
}

template <typename T>
void Node<T>::setNext(Node<T>* n) {
    m_Next = n;
}

template <typename T>
void Node<T>::setPrev(Node<T>* p) {
    m_Prev = p;
}

template <typename T>
void Node<T>::setData(const T& data) {
    m_Data = data;
}

template <typename T>
T Node<T>::getData() {
    return m_Data;
}

#endif


#ifndef LINKEDLIST_H
#define LINKEDLIST_H
//#include "Node.h"
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

template <typename T>
class LinkedL
{
public:
    LinkedL();
    ~LinkedL();
    LinkedL(const LinkedL<T>& rhs);
    LinkedL<T>& operator=(const LinkedL<T>& rhs);

    void insertFirst(const T& data);
    void insertLast(const T& data);
    void insertAfter(const T& key, const T& data);
    void destroy();

    bool isEmpty();
    int getSize()const;
    bool remove(int i);
    void traverseForward();

    T operator[](int i);

private:
    Node<T>* getNode(int i) const;
    Node<T>* m_First;
    Node<T>* m_Last;
    int m_Size;
};

template <typename T>
LinkedL<T>::LinkedL()
{
    m_First = nullptr;
    m_Last = nullptr;
    m_Size = 0;
}

template <typename T>
LinkedL<T>::~LinkedL()
{
    destroy();
}

template <typename T>
LinkedL<T>::LinkedL(const LinkedL<T>& rhs) : LinkedL() {
    *this = rhs;
}

template <typename T>
LinkedL<T>& LinkedL<T>::operator=(const LinkedL<T>& rhs) {
    if (this == &rhs) {
        return *this;
    }

    destroy();

    //m_Size = rhs.m_Size;
    Node<T>* head = new Node<T>(rhs.m_First->getData());
    insertFirst(head->getData());
    delete head; // Your missed this...

    Node<T>* current = rhs.m_First->getNext();
    while (current != nullptr) {
        insertLast(current->getData());
        current = current->getNext();
    }

    return *this;
}

template <typename T>
void LinkedL<T>::destroy() {
    if (m_First != nullptr) {
        Node<T>* current = m_First;
        while (current != nullptr) {
            Node<T>* oldNode = current;
            current = current->getNext();
            delete oldNode;
            oldNode = 0;
        }
    }
    m_First = nullptr;
}

template <typename T>
bool LinkedL<T>::isEmpty() {
    if (m_First == nullptr) {
        return true;
    } return false;
}

template <typename T>
void LinkedL<T>::insertFirst(const T& data) {
    Node<T>* newNode = new Node<T>(data);
    if (isEmpty()) {
        m_First = newNode;
        m_Last = newNode;
    }
    else {
        m_First->setPrev(newNode);
        newNode->setNext(m_First);
        m_First = newNode;
    }
    m_Size++;
}

template <typename T>
void LinkedL<T>::insertAfter(const T& key, const T& data) {
    if (isEmpty()) {
        return;
    }
    Node<T>* current=0;
    for (int i = 0; i < this->getSize(); i++) {
        if (this->operator[](i) == key) {
            current = this->getNode(i);
        }
    }
    Node<T>* newNode = new Node<T>(data);
    if (current == 0) {
        cout << "Node could not be found." << endl;
        return;
    }
    else if (current==m_Last) {
        m_Last = newNode;
        newNode->setNext(nullptr);
    }
    else {
        current->getNext()->setPrev(newNode);
        newNode->setNext(current->getNext());
    }
    current->setNext(newNode);
    newNode->setPrev(current);
    m_Size++;
}

template <typename T>
int LinkedL<T>::getSize() const{
    return m_Size;
}

template <typename T>
void LinkedL<T>::insertLast(const T& data) {
    Node<T>* newNode = new Node<T>(data);
    if (isEmpty()) {
        m_Last = newNode;
        m_First = newNode;
    }
    else {
        m_Last->setNext(newNode);
        newNode->setPrev(m_Last);
        m_Last = newNode;
    }
    m_Size++;
}

template <typename T>
T LinkedL<T>::operator[](int i) {
    int counter = 0;
    Node<T>* current = m_First;

    while (true) {
        if (counter == i) {
            return (current->getData());
        }
        current = current->getNext();
        counter++;
    }
}

template <typename T>
Node<T>* LinkedL<T>::getNode(int i) const{
    int counter = 0;
    Node<T>* current = m_First;
    if (i<0 && i>=this->getSize()) {
        return nullptr;
    }
    while (true) {
        if (counter == i) {
            return current;
        }
        current = current->getNext();
        counter++;
    }
}

template <typename T>
bool LinkedL<T>::remove(int i) {

    if (isEmpty() || i<0 || i>=getSize()) {
        cout << "No nodes to remove in specified index" << endl;
        return false;
    }
    Node<T>* iNode = getNode(i);

    if (getSize()==1) { //only 1 element in the list
        m_Last = iNode->getNext();
        m_First = nullptr;
        delete iNode;
    }
    else if (i==0) { //remove first element
        Node<T>* next = getNode(i + 1);
        next->setPrev(nullptr);
        m_First = next;
        delete iNode;
    }
    else if(i==(getSize()-1)){//remove last element
        Node<T>* prev = getNode(i - 1);
        prev->setNext(nullptr);
        m_Last = prev;
        delete iNode;
    }
    else { //remove "sandwiched" element
        Node<T>* prev = getNode(i - 1);
        Node<T>* next = getNode(i + 1);
        prev->setNext(next);
        next->setPrev(prev);
        delete iNode;
    }
    m_Size--;
    return true;
}

template <typename T>
void LinkedL<T>::traverseForward() {
    for (int i = 0; i < getSize(); i++) {
        cout << "[" << i << "] " << this->operator[](i) << "  ";
    }
}

#endif // !LINKEDLIST_H


#include <iostream>
//#include "LinkedL.h"
//#include "Node.h"
using std::cout;
using std::endl;



int main() {

    LinkedL<int> list;
    list.insertFirst(31);
    list.insertLast(23);
    list.insertAfter(23, 67);
    list.insertAfter(23, 45);
    LinkedL<int> list1(list);
    list.destroy();
    list1.traverseForward();

    system("PAUSE");
}
```

Finally I strongly recommend to read about [RAII](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Resource_Acquisition_Is_Initialization), this will improbe your skills.